# Strange behaviour when passing objects into classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

How come foo doesn't update in myClass2 using a bool (Example 1) but it works if I use a list (example 2). I'm guessing to save memory the interpreter uses a reference when passing a list but makes a copy when using bools, ints, etc? how can I pass a refrence instead? I am trying to avoid using global. (Python 3.7.0)

Example 1

```
class myClass1():

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def run(self):
        print(self.foo)
        self.foo = False

class myClass2():

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def run(self):
        print(self.foo)


def main():

    foo = True

    c1 = myClass1(foo)
    c2 = myClass2(foo)

    c1.run()
    c2.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
True
True
```

Example 2

```
class myClass1():

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def run(self):
        print(self.foo[0])
        self.foo[0] = False

class myClass2():

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def run(self):
        print(self.foo[0])


def main():

    foo = [True]

    c1 = myClass1(foo)
    c2 = myClass2(foo)

    c1.run()
    c2.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
True
False
```

Comment: No, Python *never* copies an object unless you explicitly tell it to. Please see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: You should read about mutable vs immutable objects in Python

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something today, sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: Read about [are-static-class-variables-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible)